# Iterate Object in Angular 2 firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an object in my firebase database to loop. The problem is I can't loop the push Id's on my code. So this is the structure of my database.

[image]

I can get the data using my code like this.

```
 this.userGroup = this.db.list('user_group')
 this.userGroup.subscribe(snap => {

     snap.forEach(item => {
        console.log(item); 

     });


 })
```

so this is the data that will produce. 
 [image]

If I write `console.log(item.group_company)` of course the data exist so it will display. So how can I Iterate the data on group_company. If I write

```
item.company_group.forEach(company_item => {
    console.log(company_item);
});
```

Even if I use the `item.company_group.val()` it gives me an error.

Comment: try item.company_group.val().id

Comment: I tried that but gives me an error. when I console.log(item.company_group) its an object. but when I try to loop it, it says  `item.company_group.forEach is not a function`